# Are large cell bodies of neurons harder to depolarize than small cell bodies of neurons?

Tags: neuroscience, cell-membrane, electrophysiology

In order for the axon to initiate an action potential, we know that the axon initial segment must be brought to threshold. So my question is as follows:

Say we have the minimum charge input, "X", necessary to depolarize the axon initial segment of **Neuron 1**.

Now, we have **Neuron 2**, which has a larger soma. Will this same input X be sufficient to depolarize the axon initial segment of **Neuron 2**?

I am trying to explore how physical concepts like capacitance manifest in biological systems. **Neuron 1**'s soma (approximated as a sphere) presumably has a lower capacitance than **Neuron 2**'s soma (approximated as a sphere), due to the difference in cross sectional area of the somas. Therefore, I would assume that **Neuron 2's axon initial segment requires greater input to depolarize than Neuron 1's axon initial segment**.

Is this simplistic idealization of somas actually observed in experiments?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, in order to attain the depolarization necessary to trigger an action potential you need more charge in the bigger neuron. This is simply because you have a larger capacitor.

Comment: Great! Knowing this, could you please explain then, WHY larger diameter axons convey action potentials more quickly than smaller diameter axons? (assume they are both equally myelinated) Shouldn't the larger diameter axons "require more charge to depolarize" and therefore actually take longer to convey an action potential?

Comment: Larger axons also have more sodium channels, so they move more charge. The reason why larger axons have faster conduction is because the have less internal resistance.

Comment: Can't I apply that exact same logic to the soma of the neuron? It has a larger diameter...therefore it has less internal resistance...it has a larger diameter, therefore it has more surface area available for ion channels to be present...etc

AND YET the conclusions are different between the two: big axon depolarizes more quickly but big soma depolarizes more slowly.

Comment: The soma doesn`t contain voltage dependent sodium channels, the voltage is propagated in a passive way. In the axons, conduction is active even though if you have an external input, larger axons need more charge. You can play with axon simulation in this web page http://nerve.bsd.uchicago.edu/nervejs/MAP.html you can change parameters of the axon such as the radius or stimulus amplitude and see how that affects the propagation of the action potential.

Comment: I will say that the main source of your confusion is between propagation velocity and charge needed for depolarization. They are related, but they don`t mean the same.

Comment: within the myelinated segments of an axon, however, the voltage IS propagated in a passive way. So I still fail to see how for the same conditions, different results are observed between axons and somas.

Comment: I really recommend that you run neuron simulations to see how the different parameters you`re interested affect conduction velocity. This program will allow you to play with myelination and axon diameter https://neuron.yale.edu/neuron/

Comment: Again, larger axons need more "stimulus" or charge to reach the threshold for the propagated axon. Nevertheless larger axons have more sodium channels in the node of ranvier, so the only difference will be the length constant. Somas don`t have sodium channels so you need more external stimulus to charge the membrane.