# Why do larger diameter myelinated axons have greater conduction velocities than small diameter myelinated axons?

Tags: neuroscience, cell-membrane, electrophysiology

A canonical statement I have frequently read is that *"large diameter axons conduct action potentials at faster velocities than small diameter axons"*. After recently learning the effect of increased capacitance on the cell membrane (namely, that more charge is required for depolarization to occur...[Are large cell bodies of neurons harder to depolarize than small cell bodies of neurons?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82883/are-large-cell-bodies-of-neurons-harder-to-depolarize-than-small-cell-bodies-of)), I find this canon to be rather confusing.

I have attached a picture to make my question clearer: [image: Axon Diamter]

In the above picture, both neurons have the same myelin spacing. So, my question is why should the action potential in Axon B traverse the distance X1 to X2 more quickly than in Axon A. Shouldn't the increased capacitance of Axon B (due to its increased diameter) increase the time it takes for the action potential to travel between the two points?

Answer (score 3):

*Why should the action potential in Axon B traverse the distance X1 to X2 more quickly than in Axon A?*

The larger the diameter of the axon, the less the longitudinal resistance, so the current can propagate along the axon more easily.

*Shouldn't the increased capacitance of Axon B (due to its increased diameter) increase the time it takes for the action potential to travel between the two points?*

Both, the capacitance and the number of ion channels increase quadratically whit the diameter. So the increase in capacitance is compensated by an increase in total ionic current.

[Wiki cable therory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_theory)